# How to create type by picking keys from an object that have values

Tags: typescript

So I've got this big object

```js
const bigObject = {
  propA: "sup",
  propB: "hi",
  propC: undefined,
  propD: "",
  propE: "hello",
  propF: null,
}
```

And I want to make a type which is the keys of my `bigObject`, but only if that key has a value:

```js
// what I have so far which doesn't quite work
type LittleObject = {
  [x in keyof typeof bigObject]: number
}
```

↑↑↑↑ This type is too permissive. It shapes objects so their keys could be anything from `propA` to `propF`. I want a type that would only allow `propA`, `probB`, and `propE` because they have truthy values.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBPdxW) work for your use case?  Note that your definition of `bigObject` widens all the string-values property types to `string`, at which point it is impossible to see that `propD` is falsy but `propA` is truthy.  You need a `const` assertion or something like it.  Let me know if this suffices and I can write up an answer; or say what the problem is and maybe I can address it.

Comment: To be clear, are the values of these props static or dynamic?  This is easy to do for small fixed values and hard to do for dynamic ranges.  E. g. properly typing `filterObject(anything, (key, value) => isNumber(value) ? value > 100 : value != null)` so it returns `{ only: valid, key: value, pairs: here }` requires full-on dependent types, which I don't _think_ you can model in TypeScript reliably.

Comment: See also https://www.javiercasas.com/articles/typescript-dependent-types for a way to get started (though I don't think it will take you the whole way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use key remapping to test each key for the types you want and then conditionally set the key to `never` to remove it from the resulting object type.

```
const bigObject = {
  propA: "sup",
  propB: "hi",
  propC: undefined,
  propD: "",
  propE: "hello",
  propF: null,
} as const
// added as const so you can tell the difference so that
// "" does not get widened to string

type LittleObject = {
  [
    K in keyof typeof bigObject as
      (typeof bigObject)[K] extends null | undefined | ""
        ? never
        : K
  ]: number 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgSwOYHk4CsCmxYF4YDeAUDDAA4BOIZAggFwwBEEArmYwDQnlVkBCDRgAsEnbpWoBhBizAATTADMEYTHK6kJZACKCxm3gFFBQzABszIfT2oAxBmBYWuAXxgBDCDFCQoRIlAAnmSYMAAyCFBQZphoWDgw+MSkANrcpADSMCowANaYgSCKMEEhRfDIcdiwnumkMAAUpZjliKgY1QCUKRkAujCYAB5QmPJejhYwAD4wsgrKqnLTTIx19TAA-DCqAG6YFGv1DBncvQ4sALZw+zBELkA)

---

Admittedly, this is a little odd though. A property type is unlikely to be just `undefined` in practice. Usually it's `undefined | something` which means you probably do want that prop to test it. But it's hard to give specific advice from what you've provided so far in your question.